How can i eliminate close parameter in below code
how i can eliminate below error in this code
Error
Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But 'Close' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
=SPARKLINE(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",EDATE(TODAY(),-12),TODAY()),0,2))*125)
i want to make a sparkline with additon of quantity of stocks 125 nos.
